# Null pointer not staying Null in C

Tags: c, pointers, null

So my problem right now is that for some reason, I designate a pointer as `NULL` in the first function to be called, but then when I check it later, it's not `NULL` anymore.

So I have a few structs, detailed here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct filenode {
  struct filenode *next, *prev;
  const char *name;
} Filenode;

typedef struct foldernode {
  struct foldernode *next, *root, *subdir, *prev;
  Filenode *filenodes;
  const char *name;
} Folders;

typedef struct Filesystem {
  Folders *current;
} Filesystem;
```

And then I go to my actual file, where I initialize the `Filesystem`.

This is the initialization function:

```
void mkfs(Filesystem *files) {
  /* Initializes space for the filesystem itself */
  files = malloc(sizeof(*files));

  if(files == NULL) {
    printf("Memory allocation failed!\n");
    return;
  }
  /* Initializes space for the first root node */
  files->current = malloc(sizeof(files->current));

  if(files->current == NULL) {
    printf("Memory allocation failed!\n");
    return;
  }

  files->current->filenodes = NULL;
}
```

Now, when I go into the next function, mkdir, and I check if `files->current->filenodes = NULL`, and it is not `NULL` anymore. I'm extremely confused right now. And yes, the same `*files` variable is being passed in to every function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, you say you can't change the signature of `mkfs()`. I'm going to assume it's called like this:

```
 Filesystem files;
 mkfs(&files);
```

If that's the case, you don't need to create space for the structure (since it's created on the stack just before your `mkfs()` call), so you can remove this line:

```
  files = malloc(sizeof(*files));
```

Removing this line will fix the problem that you can't see the changes to `files` after the function has returned. This was causing you trouble since **C is always pass by value** - the malloc was changing the value of the local copy of the `files` pointer, meaning that no further changes were seen outside your function.

---

You will also run into trouble with this line:

```
files->current = malloc(sizeof(files->current));
```

Since `files->current` is a pointer to a `struct foldernode`, the sizeof call only tells you the size of the pointer. You probably meant:

```
files->current = malloc(sizeof(struct foldernode));
```

or:

```
files->current = malloc(sizeof(Folders));
```

Comment: Actually, in my driver, I have mkfs(&files).

Comment: @Nav: That changes nothing, it is still a copy.  There is no such thing as pass by reference in C.

Comment: @Nav: How is files defined in your driver?

Comment: @Nav: I've updated my "assuming you previously had" to be closer to what I think you've got :)

Comment: Ah sorry for the delay in answering. But I would definitely change these things, if there wasn't the fact that this is for a school project, and therefore we have set headers and the test drivers are provided, and I'm not sure if we can step outside those lines.

Comment: To be more clear, the header I listed above is the header that we're supposed to use, and the driver uses Filesystem f, mkfs(&f)

Comment: @Nav: I've updated my answer with a version that will work without you needing to change the function signature.

Comment: +1 since this is the only answer that *really* addresses the problem now that the OP has explained that he cannot change the signature

Comment: You are such an amazing person. Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: You're welcome :) If this answer solved it for you, don't forget to click the tick next to it to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

> And yes, the same "*files" variable is being passed in to every function.

as a *copy* of the real variable which won't be reflected back to the caller.

Your `mkfs` is broken. It assigns the result of `malloc` to the *local* copy of `files`, which is then tossed away on exit.

You will need something like:

```
void mkfs(Filesystem **pFiles) {
  /* Initializes space for the filesystem itself */
  *pFiles = malloc(sizeof(FileSystem));

  if(*pfiles == NULL) {
    printf("Memory allocation failed!\n");
    return;
  }
  /* Initializes space for the first root node */
  (*pFiles)->current = malloc(sizeof((*pfiles)->current));

  if((*pFiles)->current == NULL) {
    printf("Memory allocation failed!\n");
    free (*pFiles);    // <-- to avoid memory leaks
    return;
  }

  (*pFiles)->current->filenodes = NULL;
}
```

and to call it with:

```
FileSystem *files;
mkfs (&files);
```

By passing in a *pointer* to the pointer, you can reflect any changes back to the original. This scheme should be used for any variable you want to change in a function and have reflected back.

Now you may *think* you're already doing that because you're passing in a pointer but, when it's the actual pointer that you want to change, you need the double-pointer.

You'll also notice that I've added a `free` call to free the first allocation if the second fails. That's needed to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: However, when I originally called mkfs, I passed in mkfs(&files), so shouldn't that pass by value, not a copy?

Comment: @Nav: You seem to have misunderstood the term.  Pass by value means "make a copy", and that's the only type of passing you can do in C.  There is no "pass by reference" (which is really what you meant) in C.

Comment: @Nav: Depends on the type of `files`. It should be a `FileSystem *`, in which case `&files` would work. If it's just a `FileSystem`, you have the problem described in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
void mkfs(Filesystem *files)
```

Here the pointer `files` is passed by *copy*.  This is not the pointer you declared and passed to the function, but instead a copy of that pointer which points to the same memory location.  The pointers themselves reside in different memory locations.

```
files = malloc(sizeof(*files));
```

Here you assign a new value to the pointer `files`.  However, this is again just a *copy* of the original pointer.  So you give the copy a new value, but the original pointer remains unchanged.

If you need to assign a new value to the argument itself (not simply mutate what it points to, but actually assign a new value to it) then you need to pass a pointer to pointer.

```
void mkfs(Filesystem **files) {
    /* Initializes space for the filesystem itself */
    *files = malloc(sizeof(Filesystem));
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to correct the answers below/above - Instead of doing

```
Type *pType;
pType = (Type *) malloc (sizeof (pType)); // <- the size allocated is for a pointer
```

What you want to do is

```
Type *pType;
pType = (Type *) malloc (sizeof (*pType)); // <- now allocates space for Type!
```

This is a common mistake...

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the OP's code where he does what you say he is doing.

Comment: @EdS I'm talking about the answers. Most make the mistake I'm talking about. See paxdiablos' answer for example. Other have corrected...

Comment: Also the OP code has the statement files->current = malloc (sizeof(files->current)); and that is wrong!